# System Text json deserialize string with escaped character

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I've got the string value :

```
var jsonStringValue= "[{\"id\": \"001\",\"schoolName\": \"Johnson Primary School\",\"rules\": \"[{\\\"key\\\":\\\"bc92f\\\",\\\"student\\\":\\\"peter\\\",\\\"class\\\":\\\"6A\\\"},{\\\"key\\\":\\\"c929\\\",\\\"student\\\":null,\\\"class\\\":null}]\"}]"
```

and I want to expect to produce the JsonObject or dynamic object as below

```
[
    {
        "id": "001",
        "schoolName": "Johnson Primary School",
        "rules": [
            {
                "key": "bc92f",
                "student": "peter",
                "class": "6A"
            },
            {
                "key": "c929",
                "student": null,
                "class": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I cannot do it in this code :

```
var jsonObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(jsonStringValue);
```

because the rules inside contain slash or sometime it have \r\n
can I know how to convert it by using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer in dotnet 6?

Thank you

Comment: Your first code block is not valid C# because the double quotes that you want inside the string are not escaped.

Comment: In addition, it's going to be hard to produce a JsonObject if your Json is an _array_. Why do you want to deserializeto this type? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Because, I need to convert it into object and check the nest object "rules" have any invalid value inside

Comment: X/Y problem, ask about that instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not deserialize it to JsonObject directly since your json is a JsonArray, but you can deserialize it  using this code

```
JsonObject jObj= (JsonObject) System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
               .Deserialize<System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonArray>(jsonStringValue)[0];
```

The problem is that the "rules" property inside of your json is serialized twice. So you can parse it twice

```
var jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(jsonStringValue);
jsonNode[0]["rules"] = JsonNode.Parse(jsonNode[0]["rules"]);
```

new json

```
string json= jsonNode.ToString();
```

result

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "schoolName": "Johnson Primary School",
    "rules": [
      {
        "key": "bc92f",
        "student": "peter",
        "class": "6A"
      },
      {
        "key": "c929",
        "student": null,
        "class": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

or if you want a JsonObject

```
JsonObject jObj = (JsonObject) System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
          .Deserialize<System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonArray>(jsonNode.ToString())[0];
```